# How to append each sibling element to its sibling in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have div's in wordpress and each div has a `<ul></ul>`

```
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="elimore_trim">
    Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <ul class="hyrra-forrad-size-list">
    <li>Hyra 1</li>
    <li>Content 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
    <div class="elimore_trim">
    Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <ul class="hyrra-forrad-size-list">
    <li>Hyra 2</li>
    <li>Content 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to append each `class="hyrra-forrad-size-list"` to its sibling `class="list-item"`

My current jquery code looks like below:

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(function() {
  j('.list-item .hyrra-forrad-size-list').each(function() {
    j(this).appendTo('.elimore_trim');
  });
});
```

The problem with my code above is that all elements that have the class `hyrra-forrad-size-list` is being inserted to each element that has a class of `elimore_trim`

For example:

```
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="elimore_trim">
    Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <ul class="hyrra-forrad-size-list">
    <li>Hyra 1</li>
    <li>Content 1</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="hyrra-forrad-size-list">
    <li>Hyra 2</li>
    <li>Content 2</li>
    </ul>

</div>

<div class="list-item">
    <div class="elimore_trim">
    Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <ul class="hyrra-forrad-size-list">
    <li>Hyra 1</li>
    <li>Content 1</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="hyrra-forrad-size-list">
    <li>Hyra 2</li>
    <li>Content 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Do you know how can i just transfer the class `hyrra-forrad-size-list` to its own sibling only? Any idea is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) and [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) both works same, their syntax is little bit different.

[`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the target like

```
$(element_to_be_append).appendTo(append_to_this);
```

[`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/)  insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements like

```
$(append_to_this).appendTo(element_to_be_append);
```

Target the [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the element specific element you want to append.

**Using [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/):**

```js
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(function() {
  j('.list-item .hyrra-forrad-size-list').each(function() {
    j(this).parent().find('.elimore_trim').appendTo(j(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="elimore_trim">
    Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <ul class="hyrra-forrad-size-list">
    <li>Hyra 1</li>
    <li>Content 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
    <div class="elimore_trim">
    Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <ul class="hyrra-forrad-size-list">
    <li>Hyra 2</li>
    <li>Content 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Using [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/):**

```js
var j = jQuery.noConflict();

j(function() {
  j('.list-item .hyrra-forrad-size-list').each(function() {
    j(this).append(j(this).parent().find('.elimore_trim'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-item">
    <div class="elimore_trim">
    Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <ul class="hyrra-forrad-size-list">
    <li>Hyra 1</li>
    <li>Content 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="list-item">
    <div class="elimore_trim">
    Lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <ul class="hyrra-forrad-size-list">
    <li>Hyra 2</li>
    <li>Content 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Worked like a charm

Comment: @ConanCarroll, I have updated the answer trying to explain the differences between `appendTo()` and `append()`....you can have a look........thanks.